# Add maphilight in image inside Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I have a 7446x1800 image that I need to map. I used maphilight jQuery plugin to achieve this. I was able to make it work(see [**here**](http://polomemorialpark.com/show_map.php) ) but what I want to achieve is to make it work inside a Bootstrap modal. I'm guessing it has something to do with z-index but I can't make it work.

The process is, when the user clicks on the smaller version of the image, a bootstrap modal will pop up where he/she could view the whole image and choose a 'lot' to make a reservation. Different colors are used to indicate whether a lot is already taken, reserved, or still available.

Here's my whole code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .modal.modal-wide .modal-dialog {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .modal-wide .modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  #tallModal .modal-body p { margin-bottom: 900px }
</style>

<div class="row">
<div class="zoomTarget" data-debug="true">
    <img src ="../../assets/images/uploads/map-1.png" alt="map 1" width="755px" height="200px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showmapModal-1">
    <div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="showmapModal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="showmapModal-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title" id="showmapModal-1">Reserve Lot</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                         <div id="veg_demo">
                            <img class="map" id="map-<?php echo $_GET['map']; ?>" src="../../assets/images/uploads/map-1.png" usemap="#map-1" >
                            <div style="clear:both; height:8px;"></div>
                            <div id="selections" style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <map pid="map-1" name="map-1">
                            <?php
                                $plot_map = SelectAll('pmp_lot_map');
                                if($plot_map){
                                    $counter = 1;
                                    if(mysqli_num_rows($plot_map) > 0) {
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($plot_map)) {
                                                $lot_map_uuid = $row['uuid'];
                                                $block_no = $row['block_no'];
                                                $lot_no = $row['lot_no'];
                                                $coordinates = $row['coords'];
                                                $lot_status = $row['status'];
                                                if($lot_status == 'available') {
                                                    $fillColor = '87D37C';
                                                    $message = "This lot is available. Do you really want to reserve this Block # ".$block_no.", Lot # ".$lot_no.".";
                                                } else if($lot_status == 'reserved') {
                                                    $fillColor = 'F4D03F';
                                                    $message = "This lot is already reserved.";
                                                } else if($lot_status == 'taken') {
                                                    $fillColor = '96281B';
                                                    $message = "This lot is not available.";
                                                }
                            ?>
                            <area data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal_<?php echo $counter; ?>" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"000000","strokeWidth":3,"fillColor":"<?php echo $fillColor; ?>","fillOpacity":1}' href="#" shape="poly" coords="<?php echo $coordinates; ?>" data-alt="Block <?php echo $block_no; ?> Lot <?php echo $lost_no; ?>" data-title="Block <?php echo $block_no; ?> Lot <?php echo $lot_no; ?>">
                            <div class="modal fade" id="mapModal_<?php echo $counter; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mapModalLabel-<?php echo $counter; ?>">
                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                       <div class="modal-content">
                                              <div class="modal-header">
                                                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                     <h4 class="modal-title" id="mapModalLabel-<?php echo $counter; ?>">Reserve Lot</h4>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="modal-body">
                                                     <p style="text-indent:0;">
                                                        <?php echo $message; ?>
                                                    </p>

                                              </div>
                                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                                     <?php if($lot_status == 'available') {?><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="saveMapModal('<?php echo $lot_map_uuid; ?>','mapModal_<?php echo $counter; ?>','<?php echo $uuid; ?>');">Continue</button><?php } ?>
                                                     <?php if($lot_status == 'available') {?><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button><?php } ?>
                                                     <?php if($lot_status != 'available') {?><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button><?php } ?>
                                              </div>
                                       </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                            <?php
                                            $counter++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </map>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
           </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.map').maphilight();
});
$(".modal-wide").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
    var height = $(window).height() - 100;
    $(this).find(".modal-body").css("max-height", height);
});
</script>
```

Or if it's not possible, are there any other ways to achieve it?

Any help is highly appreciated.

P.S. I can't tag "maphilight" plugin because it says it needs to have 1500 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
style="position:absolute;"
```

is the culprit. I removed it when I use the maphilight in modal and everything seems to work!

Comment: Where did you erase that?

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
//id or class where you click to activate the modal
$('.the_modal_click').on('click', function() {
  //after activating the modal, activate maphilight
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.modal img').maphilight();
  }, 300);
});
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.